# How to get the href content of a link tag

Tags: php, css, dom, curl, html-parsing

I have a `link` tag. I want to get the `href` so that I can get the external CSS code.

This is what I tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css">
<?php

    include('simple_html_dom.php');  
    $html = new simple_html_dom();  

    $html->load_file("test.txt");

    $file = fopen("link.txt","w");

    $link=$html->find("link");
    foreach($link AS $lk){
     $lk->href;

    $line_string=file_get_contents($lk);
    fwrite($file,($line_string. PHP_EOL));
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not assigning the lk value to anything

```
$lk->href;
```

that returns the value of the href but doesn't assign it to anything.  should be more like:

```
$link=$html->find("link");
foreach($link AS $lk){
 $hr=$lk->href;

$line_string=file_get_contents($hr);
fwrite($file,($line_string. PHP_EOL));
}
```

Comment: there is no try... Do...or do not.  --Master Yoda

Comment: i just got the idea of how to do it :)

Comment: Great! well, if this answer pointed you in the right direction, please mark it as the answer

Comment: but there's one thing,am getting the CSS codes for only one href not for the others

Comment: well, first try echoing count($link) to see how many elements it found, then try echoing $hr each time so see what you're getting

Comment: if you can't figure anything else out, then simply instead of writing, add it to a temp string and write it once at the end. put $temp=""; before the loop.  in the loop do $temp .=$line_string. PHP_EOL;  then at the end, after the loop,   fwrite($file,($temp));

Answer (score 0):

Your line "$lk->href" isn't doing anything. Try assigning it to a variable and writing that variable. For example:

```
foreach($link AS $lk){
   $href = $lk->href;
   $line_string=file_get_contents($href);
   fwrite($file,($line_string. PHP_EOL));
}
```

Comment: it works but am just getting for the last link tag as the file is being overwritten each time a new href is found

Comment: Odd that AwokeKnowing's solution works, but mine doesn't, since it appears we both copied your fwrite() code verbatim.